# Jugem Cart に EMS 送り状を PDF で出力する機能があるが、それと同等のことをやろうとすればどうすれば良いか？

Tags: pdf

こんにちは、

EMS ラベルの PDF 出力ができたらなぁ と思っているのですが、
[郵便局のダウンロードページ](http://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/download/index.html) には、EMS ラベルのテンプレートは無く、どうしたものかと思っています。

Jugem Cart では注文に対する EMS 送り状等(税関証明書など)を PDF で出力する機能があるので、
テンプレートがあるのかとおもっていましたが、何か特殊な手続きが必要になるのでしょうか？

ご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: ラベルのテンプレートって具体的に何を指していますか？ラベルのPDFであれば以下のURLにありそうですが。 https://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/information/2007/0903.html

Comment: @tomute EMS の送り状です。http://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/use/writing/ems.html ← のもので、文字が乗っかって無いパターンのものです。

Comment: フォーマットは何を期待していますか？PDFですか？PDFであればありそうですが。 https://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/information/2007/yu01645.pdf

Comment: あと質問自体が何を聞きたいのかが不明確なのですが、「Jugem CartがEMS送り状をPDFで出力する機能があるが、それと同等のことをやろうとすればどうすれば良いか？」というような質問でしょうか？

Comment: @tomute 質問の意図はおっしゃるとおりです！ pdf 有難うございます！

Comment: EMSの伝票には１件ごとに異なるお問い合わせ番号が付与されています。Jugem Cartはその番号の発行に関して日本郵便と何らかの契約をしているのだと思いますが、同様の契約を個人が行うのは難しいのではないでしょうか。　郵便局でEMSの伝票をもらってきて、それをスキャンし、データを記載した状態のPDFを作るのは、PDFのスクリプト機能を用いる事で可能だと思います。

Comment: @Fumu7 スキャン方式は、ある意味画期的です。問い合わせ番号を取得する API 的なものがあったりするのかどうか、ご存知ないでしょうか？

Comment: 問い合わせ番号は配送システムの要です。同じ番号の伝票が出回れば、EMSの業務に支障がでるので、誰でも使えるAPIのようなものは無いでしょう。日本郵便と正式な契約をした会社にだけ、何らかの方法で提供されていると思われます。　造幣局がこれから紙幣に印刷する番号を公開したりしませんよね、偽札作りに利用されますから。　EMSの問い合わせ番号も、同様に厳重なセキュリティが必要な情報ですから、簡単に入手できるとは考えられません。

Comment: @Fumu7 さん。有難うございます。そうですよね。ちなみに、「問い合わせ番号シール」みたいなものを、集荷時に貼ってくれたりする対応の有無、ご存知ないでしょうか？